# i18Next - NodeJS - How to change translations without reloading server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, i18next

I am using i18next package for NodeJS to enable translation. I am using it as standard with a json file for each language-COUNTRY pair.

I'd like to build an admin page to edit translations without having to dig into the code; then, how can I "reload" the json files once edited by admin, without having to restart the server ?

Also, is it possible to use a DB (i am using mongodb) instead of JSON files ? Would it be more appropriate in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I wish i knew the answer to how to reload the JSON files without completely re-initializing i18next-node.

In terms of storing your translations in a database, i18next-node can connect to MongoDB (as well as Redis and CouchDB): http://i18next.com/node/pages/doc_init.html#backend

Answer (score 1):

You can set

```
i18next.sync.resStore = {}
```

and then call

```
i18next.init(callback)
```

to force a reload of your preloaded languages.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use an official API of i18n with [reloadResources](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#reloadresources).

```
// reload all
i18next.reloadResources();

// reload languages
i18next.reloadResources(['de', 'fr']);

// reload namespaces for all languages
i18next.reloadResources(null, ['ns1', 'ns2']);

// reload namespaces in languages
i18next.reloadResources(['de', 'fr'], ['ns1', 'ns2']);
```