# i18next reload translation without reinit

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, plugins, i18next

I'm using I18next with the Backend plugin. My question is how to force the Backend plugin to reload translation for a particular language/namespace. The similar question regarding this nodejs plugin was asked two years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213223/i18next-nodejs-how-to-change-translations-without-reloading-server), my question is about the Backend plugin.

Comment: http://i18next.com/docs/api/#change-language does this work?

Comment: Lownthegame,  link you shared is about how to change current language.  My question is about how to reload translations for a particular language.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding, but I just found the issue on the i18next github site: https://github.com/i18next/i18next/issues/707, I tried the code snippet and it worked!

Answer (score 4):

Newer versions of `i18next` come with `i18next.reloadResources()` to reload the resources from the backend. You can optionally specify the language and/or namespaces to reload.

Further docs: https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#reloadresources